# pass variables/values from php to opened window process and vice versa

Tags: php, c++, variables

i want to have an constantly opened program (wrote in c++ prefferably).
when the php script is acessed, it will be acessed with some variables which will be passed to the active program. then the program will make some calculations, and it will pass other variables back to the php script, which will be echoed (or they can be echoed from the program too, if it is possible). after the php script ends, the program must be active!

i know that there is the command exec, and i can run a program with those params(which can be variables), but i don't want that since the program must run even if there are no active php script at that time.

i hope you understood my problem.

Comment: The program shall run on the server?

Comment: sorry...yes it is server side, it can be in the root of the webserver

Comment: That was clear. The question is if the program should run in parallel on the server or if you try to communicate with a program running on a client.

Comment: it is server side, the exe can be at the root of the webserver

Answer (score 0):

You can use [shared memory](http://php.net/manual/en/book.shmop.php) functions.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using sockets to communicate between the C++ program and the PHP script. Therefore your C++ program would act as a server and the PHP script would connect to it with the [Socket functions](http://php.net/manual/de/book.sockets.php) and localhost address. Then you could send your data between the two programs and when the PHP script ends, the C++ program would stay alive and wait for the next connection.